# Jquery error placement with required from group

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the following js and trying to integrate it with error placement.  Basically I'm trying to print the error message just for the required from group to a specific div.

I think I should use something like:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.attr("class") == "days_group" )
        error.insertAfter("#special_place");        
    else
        error.insertAfter(element);
}
```

but I'm not sure if that will work or where to place the code in what follows:

Here's a link to  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rss81/tLntbtf9/14/) (you need to get to the third page)

```
$(".next").click(function(){
                var form = $("#reg_form");
                form.validate({
                    errorElement: 'span',
                    errorClass: 'help-block',
                    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass("has-error");
                    },
                    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-error");
                    },

                    groups: {
                        days_groups: "M Tu W Th F Sa Su"
                    },



                    rules: {
                        M:{
                            require_from_group:[1,'.days_group']
                        },
                        Tu:{
                            require_from_group:[1,'.days_group']
                        },
                        W:{
                            require_from_group:[1,'.days_group']
                        },
                        Th:{
                            require_from_group:[1,'.days_group']
                        },
                        F:{
                            require_from_group:[1,'.days_group']
                        },
                        Sa:{
                            require_from_group:[1,'.days_group']
                        },
                        Su:{
                            require_from_group:[1,'.days_group']
                        }, 
                        first_name: {
                            required: true,                                                     
                        },
                        last_name: {
                            required: true,                                                     
                        },                      
                        email1 : {
                            required: true,                         
                        },
                        email2 : {
                            required: true,
                            equalTo: '#email1',
                        },
                        pass1 : {
                            required: true,                         
                        },
                        pass2 : {
                            required: true,
                            equalTo: '#pass1',                          
                        },
                        day:  {
                              require_from_group: [1, ".days-group"]
                            },




                    },
                    messages: {
                       M: {
                           require_from_group: "Please select at least 1 day"
                       },
                       Tu: {
                           require_from_group: "Please select at least 1 day"
                       },
                       W: {
                           require_from_group: "Please select at least 1 day"
                       },
                       Th: {
                           require_from_group: "Please select at least 1 day"
                       },
                       F: {
                           require_from_group: "Please select at least 1 day"
                       },
                       Sa: {
                           require_from_group: "Please select at least 1 day"
                       },
                       Su: {
                           require_from_group: "Please select at least 1 day"
                       },                       
                        first_name: {
                            required: "First name required",
                        },
                        last_name:  {
                            required: "Last name required",
                        },                      
                        email1: {
                            required: "Email required",
                        },
                        email2: {
                            required: "Confirm Email required",
                             equalTo: "Emails do not match",
                        },
                        pass1: {
                            required: "Password required",
                        },
                        pass2: {
                            required: "Confirm password required",
                             equalTo: "Passwords do not match",
                        },                      






                    }



                });
```

Comment: Couldn't you take the time to construct a jsFiddle that goes straight to the problem rather than making us fill out most of your form?  I don't want to do this every time I tweak your code.

Comment: sorry sparky, i've been working on this all day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.hasClass("days_group")) {
        error.insertAfter("#special_place");
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
}
```

**Proof of Concept:  http://jsfiddle.net/dsj4zg21/**

Comment: Where exactly do I place that?  When I try it breaks my js.

Comment: @DCR, that came from your OP, so I expected that you already knew this was an option for the `.validate()` method.

Comment: i cut and paste just before groups: {
      days_groups: "M Tu W Th F Sa Su"
     }, and it breaks my js

Comment: @DCR, did you remember to add a comma?  See my jsFiddle edited into the answer.

Comment: you are awesome.  Thanks

Comment: can i check from element is belongs to "required_from_group"]